# angular 2 - ng-bootstrap compatibility

Tags: angular

I need to install and use ng-bootstrap in my angular 2 project.I am getting the following after compiling the project.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:1:10 
    TS2305: Module '"/Users/ddavidxavierlourdu/Desktop/angular4/ui-superadmin/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

Is there any solution to use ng-bootstrap in angular 2 or should I upgrade my angular to 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ng-bootstrap's `package.json` shows that it requires Angular 4.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

Renderer2 was introduced in the Angular 4 and latest bootstrap using Renderer2
 so you need change use to older bootstrap

you can change version in package.json file

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.16",
```

`1.0.0-alpha.16` will work with angular 2

after than do `npm install` to install older version.

if you want latest bootstrap than you need use latest angular.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is fixed with your help

Comment: Not working for me with angular version 2.4.7. I even tried with `1.0.0-alpha.0`, no luck.